# git push hangs on the "Total" line only for a specific branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-remote, git-config

I'm trying to push 4 commits on a specific local branch to my remote repository which is on a private Git server. The push progress is displayed as follows:

```
Enumerating objects: 152, done.
Counting objects: 100% (152/152), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (105/105), 13.92 KiB | 4.64 MiB/s, done.
Total 105 (delta 59), reused 68 (delta 26), pack-reused 0
```

And it hangs there after the 'Total' line. I've tried waiting for more than 10 minutes, but no luck. The commits do not have any large files, all are text files with small changes.

I have tried the following based on responses for similar issues:

1. Increased the git buffer size by running `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`
2. Did a git garbage collection by running `git gc`
3. Ran a `git push -u origin <branch-name>`

**Important Note: This only happens for one specific branch, I can push changes as usual on other branches.**

PS: I'm on Windows 11, tried GUI clients, Git inside Visual Studio, and git via Terminal, no luck.

Comment: Try `GIT_TRACE=1 git push ...` to print more logs. It's supposed to print in which low-level command it gets stuck.

Comment: @ElpieKay This is what it printed. Nothing helpful I suppose. [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/Mp70VdN7/git-trace.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find a direct solution, I was able to find a workaround to solve my issue. Here's what I did.

1. Did a reset on the outgoing commits by running `git reset --soft <hash>`
2. Through trial and error found that it was one specific file that caused the issue. I was able to commit every other file except for this.
3. Copied the contents of this file onto a new file outside the repository.
4. Deleted the file and committed. Pushed successfully.
5. Copied over the new file to where it belongs, committed it, and pushed.